# Any known issues running CarrIOTA Field and CarrIOTA Nelson on the same server?

Tags: iri-node, nelson

I have a full node and will probably attempt to install both [CarrIOTA Field](https://github.com/SemkoDev/field.cli) and [CarrIOTA Nelson](https://github.com/SemkoDev/nelson.cli) on it.

Being that Nelson manages connections to neighbors and Field manages work from other Field nodes, a concern that I had is whether they might "step on each toes" so to speak.

Are there any known issues with running both of them on the same the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, I run both on the same node. I think they work in tandem actually.

If for some reason a problem arises, it will be reported at one of these two repositories:

https://github.com/SemkoDev/field.cli/issues

https://github.com/SemkoDev/nelson.cli/issues

Comment: The fact that you don't have any issues doesn't answer the question of there are known issues.

Comment: I had assumed that the OP was asking if they would conflict (i.e. Field included Nelson functionality), which they do not. Nevertheless, I've added in a link to the GitHub repositories of each so that the OP knows where to check "known issues" if any arise for whatever reason.